# Magento 2: The style.css inside Magento installation directory is effecting cache

Tags: css, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache, styles

I am very new to **Magento**. Recently I have to add extra styles to my magento website. So I go to **`adminpanel -> content-> design->configuration->my theme ->HTML`** Head

I add the following line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://example.com/my-style/style.css" />
```

Then I save that one. Now new styles are working on my website. But I edited some of the styles through opening the file through Filezilla and edit. After that, I uploaded. Then I noticed that new changes are not coming. So I open `https://example.com/my-style/style.css` in a browser so I can see that it is not updated the copy. I refresh the page and I open in incognito window. Still the same. But when I open in the same file through editor using FileZilla I can see that it is updated copy.

Then I try to refresh page cache, layout cache but the result is the same.

> i am using FileZilla for accessing the file . i don't have the
>   terminal . Please help

Comment: try sudo rm -rf var/cache/* generated/* pub/static/*  php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: i dont understand. this is any command line ? whee i have to execute ?

Comment: did you try after clear cache/ generated and static folders ?

Comment: no . Because i dont know how to do that .  I try to refresh page cache, layout cache .

Comment: please check answer

Comment: Can you please share the CSS file path placed under your website?

Comment: css file is simple file containing some font size and colors .

Comment: Where it is placed on your website?
Please share the folder structure. for example: your_theme/web/css/styles.css

Comment: /var/www/html/my-style/style.css

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll provide a solution for the same.

Comment: cloudfare is enable in your site?

Comment: yes. Cloudfare enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said that, you've inserted the CSS file directly on in the header which is placed under `/var/www/html/my-style/style.css`.

You need to flush the CDN and Server caches as well if they are enabled on the website.

As you've shared, your site has enabled the Cloudfare, then you need to flush the cache for the below path from Cloudfare

```
/var/www/html/my-style/style.css
```

Also, you can add a custom CSS file in your theme by adding a CSS file to the below path:

```
/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your_theme]/web/css/your_css_file
```

Include the created file by adding it to `/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your_theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` with below content.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/your_css_file.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Below is the official guide to include custom CSS files in your theme.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: ok . could you please suggest the good path & method to put new style sheet in my website .

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a review.

Comment: very useful information . thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, John. Happy coding!!!

Comment: before i am searching for official magento documentation , that time i didn't find out .  But now you helped me to get the documentation . Really thank you .